# Css and js files are not loading when using Nginx with docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

"How can I properly configure Nginx to serve static files for both the server and client in a Docker Compose setup? I have a Nginx configuration and a Docker Compose file, but I'm confused about how to provide the static files. I know that I can use Docker volumes, but I'm not sure how to set it up correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated."

Nginx Configuration:

```
upstream backend {
    server server:4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tutortrek.online;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://tutortrek_client;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

     location /static {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
    }
}
```

Docker Compose File:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: abin11/tutortrek_client:latest
    container_name: tutortrek_client
    ports:
      - "3000"
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - connection_network
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
        reservations:
          memory: 512M
          
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: abin11/tutortrek_server:latest
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - connection_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:4000/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./.db:/data
    restart: always
    networks:
      - connection_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_files:/usr/share/nginx/html/static  # Mount the volume to serve static files
    depends_on:
      - server
      - client
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - connection_network

networks:
  connection_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_files:  # Define the static_files volume
```